# What are Python implementation of nextInt(), hasNext() from Java?

Tags: java, python

I have this input file

```
1 2
10 2
81 3
23 6
2537857295 19
34271891003654321 1267253
```

I am reading the file like this

```
with open("powersearch.txt") as fileIn:
    for line in fileIn:
        print line
```

I am wondering if I want to, for every single line, have the 1st integer stored as `firstNum`, the 2nd stored as `secondNum`. With Java I can use a `scanner` and do `nextInt()` and `hasNext()` to get the integers, what are the equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well to parse an int from a string you just use `int(s)`, where `s` is the string.

I think this would be the most logic way in your example:

```
with open("powersearch.txt") as fileIn:
    for line in fileIn:
        n1, n2 = (int(s) for s in line.split())
        print(n1, n2)
```

Python is a different language than Java, and in my opinion more expressive (I can do more in one line than I can in Java and still write readable code). If you try to write Java stuff in Python you'll find the language a lot less effective than it can be.

Answer (score 6):

Please discard the Java ideas.  They will just confuse you.

Python is a different language, and you must learn the Pythonic approach.

Here's an example.

```
with open("powersearch.txt") as fileIn:
    for firstNum, secondNum in ( map(int, line.split()) for line in fileIn ):
        print firstNum, secondNum
```

Comment: There's a comma missing somewhere in there

Comment: I think "map(int(line.split())" should be "map(int,line.split())".

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT - nightcracker's solution is pretty much equivalent now.*

(I'm assuming you're using Python 2.x and not 3.x from the syntax.)

It's a matter of taste, but I would prefer a mix of S.Lott and nightcracker's solutions:

```
with open("powersearch.txt") as fileIn:
    for line in fileIn:
        firstNum, secondNum = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
        print firstNum, secondNum
```

List comprehension is a bit easier to read than map for me. Destructuring assignment lets us take the two item list and assign the element values to two different local variables at once.

Comment: Better use lazy evaluation and use `(int(s) for s in line.split())` instead. If there are 100000 integers on a line the performance increase will be dramatic.

Comment: If there are not exactly two integers on the line it will result in an error anyway. If you're worried about handling such a scenario more gracefully, a generator expression is only the start.

Answer (score 0):

The answers before (`n1, n2 = (int(s) for s in line.split())`) will only work if you are using a couple of numbers. Otherwise, you will need to use the the `map` function.

```
with open("powersearch.txt") as fileIn:
    for line in fileIn:
        line_int = list(map(int, line.split()))
        print(line_int)
```